# Is Ruby statsample "mode" function correct?

Tags: ruby, statistics

Ruby's statiscts gem (Statsample) seems to be giving the wrong answer.
The mode function shouldn't return the most common iten in a array? Ex.: 4

```
irb(main):185:0> [1,2,3,2,4,4,4,4].to_vector
=>
#<Daru::Vector:34330120 @name = nil @size = 8 >
    nil
  0   1
  1   2
  2   3
  3   2
  4   4
  5   4
  6   4
  7   4

irb(main):186:0> [1,2,3,2,4,4,4,4].to_vector.mode
=> 2
```

Why it is returning **2** ?

```
ruby 2.1.6p336 (2015-04-13 revision 50298) [x64-mingw32]

statsample (2.0.1)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are right Victor! There is a bug in vector lib:

```
[1,2,3,2,4,4,4,4].to_vector
 => 
#<Daru::Vector:70255750869440 @name = nil @size = 8 >
    nil
  0   1
  1   2
  2   3
  3   2
  4   4
  5   4
  6   4
  7   4

[1,2,3,2,4,4,4,4].to_vector.frequencies
 => {1=>1, 2=>2, 3=>1, 4=>4} 
[1,2,3,2,4,4,4,4].to_vector.frequencies.values
 => [1, 2, 1, 4]
```

Then gets index of max value and returns value from base array with given index (4th position -> value `2` in your case). It's done by this [method](https://github.com/v0dro/daru/blob/master/lib/daru/maths/statistics/vector.rb):

```
    def mode
      freqs = frequencies.values
      @data[freqs.index(freqs.max)]
    end
```

## Workaround

Instead of `mode` method you can use this:

```
[1,2,3,2,4,4,4,4].to_vector.frequencies.max{|a,b| a[1]<=>b[1]}.first
 => 4
```

Answer (score 2):

I agree with what Jakub said. This is a bug in the [mode method](https://github.com/v0dro/daru/blob/master/lib/daru/maths/statistics/vector.rb) in the Vector module of daru gem. All the Vector related methods in [statsample](https://github.com/clbustos/statsample) are now based on [daru](https://github.com/v0dro/daru). I have submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/v0dro/daru/pull/66) to [daru](https://github.com/v0dro/daru) fixing this bug, hopefully this will be in the next released version.

Comment: I was about to submit pull request... damn whole glory now belongs to you ;-)

Comment: Haha, open source project are fun! :)